# GitLab CI/CD: How to deploy Kubernetes application for different environments

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I would like to automate the deployment of a simple react application in an on-prem Kubernetes environment. To achieve this, I am going to use GitLab with CI/CD pipelines.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` currently looks like this:

```
variables: 
  IMAGE_NAME: react-app
  IMAGE_TAG: 0.0.1-alpha

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - /test/signature
    - build/

stages:
  - run_tests
  - build_app
  - build_image

run_tests:
  stage: run_tests
  image: node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim
  before_script: 
    - apt update
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run test 

build_app:
  stage: build_app
  image: node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim
  script:
    - npm run build

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  image: docker:20.10.17
  services:
    - docker:20.10.17-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - echo "$REGISTRY_PASS" | docker login $REGISTRY_URL -u $REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin 
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

However, this is not the final configuration, as I am missing some important steps here. Mainly, I am not sure how to proceed in the deployment stage.

1. I would like to extract value for `IMAGE_TAG` from the package.json `"version":` value to retrieve it dynamically. Probably, I am using the [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) package for that, or is there any better solution?
2. To deploy the application, I am planning to have a generic Kubernetes manifest (deployment.yaml), where certain config values have a placeholder e.g. `namespace: $DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE`. Therefore, I would dynamically expand these values depending on the environment the pipeline is running in (development, staging, production). The deployment stage looks something like this:

```yaml
deploy_app:
  stage: deploy_app
  image: debian
  before_script:
    - |
      replace_placeholders () {
        while read line
        do
            eval echo "$line" >> $1.tmp
        done < $1
      }

      replace_placeholders $CONFIG_FILE

      mv $CONFIG_FILE.tmp deployment.yaml
  script:
    - # Do the deployment here with kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Is this the right way to achieve this? Or are there any better approaches?